# 16.04 Reboot after installation hangs Assuming drive cache: write through

Tags: system-installation

I did a fresh install of 16.04 this morning and after installation finished I am asked to reboot the system.  When I do that I get a command list or what ever and the last log says

```
No Caching mode page present
Assuming drive cache: write through
```

and it just hangs there forever.  I reluctantly did a hard restart and I'm put into the grub recovery menu where grub doesn't recognize any file systems or partitions.  Are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can check the boot log (`sudo journalctl -xb`) to see boot errors that were not shown on screen. If grub cannot detect any partitions, your boot entries may be messed up though.